# Confusion about Python operator 'is'

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Python console snapshot]

Definition of 'is' operator in python:

> is operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object
>   or not

Then how come when the id of a and list1[0] don't match, the 2nd condition is True?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: No I know about that case. Python keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256. When you create an integer in that range, you get back a reference to the already existing object. Anything outside of that creates a new reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing when you're doing `id(a) is id(list1[0])` is comparing the values returned by the `id()` function to check if they point to the same object or not. 
Those values are different objects - *EVEN IF THEY ARE THE SAME VALUE*

Check this:

```
a = 2
ll = [2]

print(a is ll[0])
print(id(a), id(ll[0]))
print(id(a) is id(ll[0]))
```

Which gives:

```
True
140707131548528 140707131548528
False
```

Now why is the first result `True`? Because of [interning](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) - all ints between -5 & 256 are pre-created objects that are reused. So every 2 in python is actually the same object. But every 140707131548528 is different

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still finding this pretty confusing but I'll get the hang of it.